# how to pass value of onclick function to global scope with jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
$('.button').on('click', function grab(){
    this.value
       //I need to use this value from outside of current function
})

console.log(grab());
```

how to pass value of `onclick` function to global scope with `jquery`? How can I do that?

Comment: declare a `var myVal;` before the click event binding and assign the value to  `myVal=this.value` and then you can use the `myVal` anywhere.if i am not gettig you wrong

Comment: not working at all ((

Comment: can you update your code in your question the way you tried it

Comment: I made something wrong. now it worked thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to declare a variable in the global scope...

```
var myVal;

$('.button').on('click', function(){
  myVal = this.value;
  console.log(myVal);
})
```

Now, `myVal` will have the correct value **after** a button click. You could test it out using another event handler somewhere else in your code. Example:

```
$(".someOtherElement").on("click",function(){
  console.log(myVal);
}
```